# I m new in Ubuntu what is and where my Windows

Tags: grub2, windows

I want to reinstall new Ubuntu because old corrupted. I have on this disk Windows so I m afraid that because this message Windowse erased. How to know during installation where it is windows on which disk sda?
The following partitions are going to be formatted:
Partition #9 of SCS1 (0,0,0) sda as ext4
Partition #10 of SCS1 (0,0,0) sda as swap

Comment: @karel It doesn't appear as if the user is trying to find the Alongside option.  He doesn't appear to be having problems with his installation.  He's just trying to be sure to identify where is Windows is installed so that he doesn't make a mistake and delete the wrong partition.

Comment: Either that or else the "Install alongside" option in the "Installation type" screen of the Ubuntu installer is missing, but the "Erase Windows and install Ubuntu" and the "Something else" options are not missing. Clearly he does not want to choose the "Erase Windows and install Ubuntu" option or else that will overwrite Windows.

Comment: He wants to overwrite his `old corrupted` Ubuntu.  He has both `ext4` and  `swap` partitions (where his old corrupted Ubuntu is installed).  Of course, he also has his Windows on his computer, which he doesn't want to make a mistake and format.  His confusion is the meaning of `Partition #9 - ext4` and `Partition #10 - swap`.

Answer (score 0):

The system is indicating that it will remove partitions `/dev/sda9`, which is an `ext4` partition and `/dev/sda10`, which is a swap partition.

Neither of those is a Windows Partitions.

You can run this command to see which partition has your Windows.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

Windows is an `ntfs` partition.

This is an extract of the `sudo fdisk -l` from a computer in my shop:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for apollo: 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D4900414-D1A2-4FC2-8DDD-3A93A9A57083

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     739327     737280   360M EFI System
/dev/sda2      739328    1001471     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1001472  785969987  784968516 374.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1924679680 1926369279    1689600   825M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  1926369280 1953523711   27154432    13G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   785971200 1899800575 1113829376 531.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1899800576 1924679679   24879104  11.9G Linux swap
```

The Windows partition is `/dev/sda3`